# Clicking on register button getting registration page in woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

I am having login form and registration on same page side by side but i want to display only login form and at the bottom i need to display a button as register once i click on register then the register form should be displayed and login form should be hided and in register if i click on login button that form should be displayed.

```
            do_action( 'woocommerce_before_customer_login_form' ); ?>
           <?php if ( get_option( 'woocommerce_enable_myaccount_registration' ) === 'yes' ) : ?>
          <div class="u-columns col2-set" id="customer_login">
          <div class="u-column1 col-1">
          <?php endif; ?>
          <h2><?php esc_html_e( 'Login', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>
          <form class="woocommerce-form woocommerce-form-login login" method="post">
        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_login_form_start' ); ?>
        <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
            <label for="username"><?php esc_html_e( 'Username or email address', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
            <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="username" id="username" autocomplete="username" value="<?php echo ( ! empty( $_POST['username'] ) ) ? esc_attr( wp_unslash( $_POST['username'] ) ) : ''; ?>" /><?php // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine ?>
        </p>
        <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
            <label for="password"><?php esc_html_e( 'Password', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
            <input class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" type="password" name="password" id="password" autocomplete="current-password" />
        </p>

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_login_form' ); ?>

        <p class="form-row">
            <?php wp_nonce_field( 'woocommerce-login', 'woocommerce-login-nonce' ); ?>
            <button type="submit" class="woocommerce-Button button" name="login" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Log in', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Log in', 'woocommerce' ); ?></button>
            <a class="woocommerce-Button button" id="registerbutton" >Register</a>

            <label class="woocommerce-form__label woocommerce-form__label-for-checkbox inline">
                <input class="woocommerce-form__input woocommerce-form__input-checkbox" name="rememberme" type="checkbox" id="rememberme" value="forever" /> <span><?php esc_html_e( 'Remember me', 'woocommerce' ); ?></span>
            </label>
        </p>
        <p class="woocommerce-LostPassword lost_password">
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( wp_lostpassword_url() ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Lost your password?', 'woocommerce' ); ?></a>
        </p>

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_login_form_end' ); ?>

    </form>

    <?php if ( get_option( 'woocommerce_enable_myaccount_registration' ) === 'yes' ) : ?>

</div>

<div class="u-column2 col-2" id="registrationforms">

    <h2><?php esc_html_e( 'Register', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>

    <form method="post" class="woocommerce-form woocommerce-form-register register" <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_register_form_tag' ); ?> >

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_register_form_start' ); ?>

        <?php if ( 'no' === get_option( 'woocommerce_registration_generate_username' ) ) : ?>

            <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
                <label for="reg_username"><?php esc_html_e( 'Username', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="username" id="reg_username" autocomplete="username" value="<?php echo ( ! empty( $_POST['username'] ) ) ? esc_attr( wp_unslash( $_POST['username'] ) ) : ''; ?>" /><?php // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine ?>
            </p>

        <?php endif; ?>

        <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
            <label for="reg_email"><?php esc_html_e( 'Email address', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
            <input type="email" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="email" id="reg_email" autocomplete="email" value="<?php echo ( ! empty( $_POST['email'] ) ) ? esc_attr( wp_unslash( $_POST['email'] ) ) : ''; ?>" /><?php // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine ?>
        </p>

        <?php if ( 'no' === get_option( 'woocommerce_registration_generate_password' ) ) : ?>

            <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
                <label for="reg_password"><?php esc_html_e( 'Password', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input type="password" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="password" id="reg_password" autocomplete="new-password" />
            </p>

        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_register_form' ); ?>

        <p class="woocommerce-FormRow form-row">
            <?php wp_nonce_field( 'woocommerce-register', 'woocommerce-register-nonce' ); ?>
            <button type="submit" class="woocommerce-Button button" name="register" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Register', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Register', 'woocommerce' ); ?></button>
                    <a class="woocommerce-Button button" id="loginbutton" >Login</a>

        </p>

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_register_form_end' ); ?>
          </form>
          </div>
          </div>
          <?php endif; ?>
          <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_customer_login_form' ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding JQUERY for that.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {
// Then hide the second div
jQuery("#registrationform").hide();

// Then add a click handlers to the buttons
jQuery("#registerbutton").click(function() {
  jQuery("#registrationform").show();
  jQuery("#loginform").hide();
});
jQuery("#loginbutton").click(function() {
  jQuery("#registrationform").hide();
  jQuery("#loginform").show();
});
}) 
</script>
```